# How to stack the divs using relative positioning?

Tags: html, css

I positioned divs relative and stacked them one below the other with fixed height. Next i am moving a div 20px up like top:-20px. the problem is for all the following divs i have to do top:-20, otherwise there is a gap of 20px. Is there a work around for this.

I have added a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xS3Kt/

html

```
<div class="class1">hello</div>
<div class="class2">hello</div>
<div class="class3">hello</div>
<div class="class4">hello</div>
```

css

```
div{
    hieght:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.class1{background:#bbb;}
.class2{top:-5px;background:#999;}
.class3{background:#777;}
.class4{background:#555;}
```

here you can see there is a gap between 3rd div and fourth div. to correct it i have to position all the following divs. is there a work around

Comment: You really need to post an example of what you mean on something like jsbin.com. Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: edited my question with fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/saDyD/) answers the question. You need to add a wrapper that groups the divs you want to shift upward.

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="class1">hello</div>
    <div class="class2">hello</div>
    <div class="class3">hello</div>
    <div class="class4">hello</div>
</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
    border: .1em solid rgb(0,0,0);
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height : auto;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    top:-5px;
}
.class1 {
    background:#bbb;
}
.class2 {
    background:#999;
}
.class3 {
    background:#777;
}
.class4 {
    background:#555;
}
```

Comment: I just amended my answer to speak more directly to the clarified question.

Comment: Are you trying to shift the whole page upward? I guess maybe I'm still not clear on the question.

Comment: The last div is a footer. if i do like you said i have a gap below my footer. how to remove that gap.

Comment: So height:auto of the wrapper does the trick. I'll try it thank you.

Comment: ```height:auto```, but also ```margin-bottom:-5px```?